# List Selects certain elements

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala. There is one question about how to select certain elements from list.

```
arr = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

for example, I want only get odd index element => 2,3,6
or skip 3 elements => 4,8
The only way I can come out is looping each element and determining, but it should be a good scala way to handle this kindle of question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function to do this is a one-liner, and does not explicitly use indices at all

```
val arr = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

def getNth[A](xs:List[A], n:Int):List[A] = xs.drop(n-1).grouped(n).map(_.head).toList

getNth(arr, 2)   // List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)
getNth(arr, 4)   // List[Int] = List(4, 8)
```

Comment: It is great. It is functional programming I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is using a `filter` with `zipWithIndex`:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).zipWithIndex.filter{x => x._2 % 2 == 1}.map{_._1}
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)

scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).zipWithIndex.filter{x => x._2 % 3 == 0}.map{_._1}
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 7)
```

Using a `toStream` will make the evaluations lazy, and potentially more efficient if you are interested in efficiency.

**Edit:**

This is another, more (less in this case) concise way to do it:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).zipWithIndex.collect{case(x,i) if i % 2 == 1 => x}
res5: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I wonder if it is very heavy cost iteration.

Comment: Its run time would be `0(n)` but yeah the leading coefficient may be large, I am not sure. This seems to be the standard approach though based on reading other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
scala> def withIndices[T](xs:Seq[T])(p: Int => Boolean ) =
          xs.zipWithIndex.filter(x => p(x._2)).unzip._1

scala> val xs = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

scala> withIndices(xs)(_%2==1)
res4: Seq[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)

scala> withIndices(xs)(_%3==0)
res5: Seq[Int] = List(1, 4, 7)
```